# Razorpay standard checkout razorpay_order_id missing in response (only razorpay_payment_id found)

Tags: javascript, html, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate the **Razorpay** payment gateway.

The payment process was a `success` but I don't get `razorpay_order_id` in response

This is my code
Pay

```
<script>
var options = {
   "key": "YOUR_KEY_ID", // Your Key
   "amount": "50000", // Amount is in currency subunits, in Paise 
   "currency": "INR",
   "name": "Acme Corp",
   "description": "Test Transaction",
   "image": "https://example.com/your_logo",
   "razorpay_order_id": "order_9A33XWu170gUtm", //This is a sample Order ID. Pass the `id` obtained in the response of Step 1
  "handler": function (response){
              alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
              alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
   
             },
  "prefill": {
     "name": "Gaurav Kumar",
     "email": "gaurav.kumar@example.com",
     "contact": "9999999999"
  },
  "notes": {
    "address": "Razorpay Corporate Office"
 },
  "theme": {
    "color": "#F37254"
  }
};

var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
   rzp1.open();
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1: Say, user selected a product and order is placed in cart with order_id="user_order_id".

2: Before making payment, first create "razor_order_id" in your database table corresponds to your product order_id=user_order_id.

3: $a = new Api(env('RAZOR_KEY'), env('RAZOR_SECRET'));

$order  = $a->order->create(['receipt' => user_order_id,
'amount'=> $cart['total_amount']*100, 'currency'=> 'INR']);

$razor_order_id = $order->id;

$razor_order_status = $order->status;

DB::table('orders')->where('order_id',$user_order_id)->update(['razor_order_id' => $razor_order_id,'razor_order_status'=>$razor_order_status]);

Session::put('razor_order_id',$razor_order_id);

4: now pass your session variable '$razor_order_id'as values to your key "razorpay_order_id" in $options.

5: now run your above script and you will receive 'razorpay_order_id' in response.